# How to prevent identifiers and string keywords from clobbering each other

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have several situations in my code like:

```
get?( id?:string ): any;
```

and worse:

```
export function urlAppend( url?:string, string?:string ): string;
```

In my parser, I have `'get'` and `'string'` defined as part of several rules, which means that it gets implicitly put into the lexer. However, they also need to be classified as `Identifiers` for property and method names.

Is there a way that I can get this to work?

(The grammar is for JavaScript and TypeScript, in case that helps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR assigns token types deterministically in the lexer. If you have context-sensitive keywords in your language, you can define an `identifier` rule in the parser to handle it:

```
identifier
  : Identifier
  | 'get'
  | 'string'
  | ... // other context-sensitive keywords
  ;
```